# How to fix page lag on load

Tags: php, css, javascript

I have a problem with my website, when you load the index page , the headers load fine but the main content appear with a delay between each photos. The error is only on the index because there is alot of contents.

Thank you very much, waiting for answers.

Link :    http://www.kinouk.com

Comment: What browser? show some code maybe... What is the "main content" refer too? and please fix your post and replace `Link : www*kinouk*com` with \[link\]\(www.kinouk.com\). Your question is of very low quality and unless you update it will likely be closed.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a page that actually has multiple images? Most don't have any content at all and I'm tired of poking around randomly.

Answer (score 0):

First guess would be that your images are massive. The flower image on [this page](https://www.kinouk.com/ads.php?Category=Furniture) is 800x600px, forced to 180x135 in-browser, and the actual file is 328k. If you do that a bunch of times in a single document, you're going to see noticeable lag as each image downloads. Your thumbnails should actually *be* thumbnails, not full-sized images crammed to a smaller size.